# Using parameters in Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using the resourceful routing for a laravel 4 application. Here is my code on the routes.php file

```
Route::resource('/users', 'UserController');
```

When i navigate to public/users/1 it works as expected, it shows the record with id = 1. Now what i noticed is when i navigate to public/users/1-xxxxxxx or any text after the id, it shows the record with id=1. 
My first question is, is this supposed to happen?

2nd question is, how would i create a url just like stackoverflow, where for example the username is included on the url after the id where the separator between them is a slash.

something like public/users/1/john.

Comment: I am unsure why you need to go to public? Supposedly I should be [domain]/users/1-xxx.

Another the id is int. Maybe you are passing the '1-xxx' as string?

Comment: Also please avoid asking two different question on a single Stackoverflow question. I think it would be much better to ask it on a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question on how to do this kind of URL like

`public/users/1/john.`

You could setup your route like:

**routes.php**

`Route::get('users/{id}/{username}', 'UserController@showUser');`

**UserController**

```
public function showUser($id, $username)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```